# How to get Part in header?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, parts

I am writing my master thesis in LaTeX. I am using the `book` document class and the fancy `fancyhdr` package. Now, I would like to have the "Part" on even and the "chapter" on odd pages. I read one of your comments and tried:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thepart. #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thechapter.\ #1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\leftmark}}}    
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\rightmark}}}
```

Unfortunately, the chapter appears on odd pages but the part is not visible on even pages? What did I do wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 6):

There exists no `\partmark` in the default [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls). As such, you also need to update `\part` to appropriately insert a newly-defined `\partmark`. The following MWE does exactly this using an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum,xcolor,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}% <cmd>
  {\markboth{}{}}% <search>
  {\partmark{#1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\newcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thepart. #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thechapter.\ #1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\leftmark}}}    
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase{\textbf{\rightmark}}}
\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

The patch to `\@part` replaces `\markboth{}{}` with `\partmark{#1}`, which accepts the first argument of `\@part` - the title associated with the ToC. Here is the original definition of `\@part` with the line that the patch replaces being highlighted:

```
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}% <------- the patch changed this into \partmark{#1}
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
```

---

A similar layout is achievable using [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) (with added page numbers in the header, for what it's worth):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,titleps,etoolbox}
\newcommand{\parttitle}{}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}% <cmd>
  {\markboth}% <search>
  {\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\newpagestyle{fancy}{%
  \setheadrule{0.2pt}%
  \sethead  [\textbf{\thepart.\ \parttitle}]%        even-left
            []%                                      even-center
            [\thepage]%                              even-right
            {\thepage}%                              odd-left
            {}%                                      odd-center
            {\textbf{\thechapter.\ \chaptertitle}}%  odd-right
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

A patch is still necessary to define `\parttitle`, which doesn't exist by default.